# My Python BeautifulSoup scraper of yahoo finance quote data has broken. Has something changed in the last week?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
def get_fy(ticker, outFile):
    global retry
    # print ( "get_fy processing", ticker, ", retry =", retry )
    try:

        # create a web driver instance
        p1 = "http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"
        p2 = "?p="
        p3 = "&.tsrc=fin-srch-v1"
        print(p1+ticker+p2+ticker)
        r = urlopen(p1+ticker+p2+ticker)
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(r,"html5lib")
        # bsObj = BeautifulSoup(r.read())
        titleList = bsObj.findAll("title")
        # title = title_re.search(r.data)
        if not titleList or titleList[0].get_text().find('Stock Price')<0:
            print ("found", len(bsObj.get_text()), "bytes" )
            print ("found title at", bsObj.get_text().find("<title>"))
            print ("found", len(bsObj.findAll("td")), "td objects")
            print (bsObj.get_text()[:70])
            if titleList: print("found titleList[0]:", titleList[0])
            else: print("titleList was not found")
            #dump = open('dump.html', 'w')
            #dump.write(bsObj.get_text())
            #dump.close()
            if retry > 2: return False
            retry = retry+1
            time.sleep(10)
            print ("retry count", retry, "for", ticker )
            return get_fy(ticker,outFile)

        elements = bsObj.findAll("td")
```

procesing F (http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/F?p=F) gives:

```
found 140676 bytes
found title at -1
found 0 td objects
▼ì½ízÓÈÒ(ú⌂]…ð♀`¿XŠ¾-ÛcX!       ♥k%„�♦Ø³xyóÈ’∟k!K▲INb2ÞÏ¹�s{çJNUuKÖ—C↕☻3³ö
titleList was not found
retry count 1 for F
```

Comment: Should this have a python 2 tag?

Comment: No, I see nothing Python 2-specific.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be first trying to get the HTML title tag for a given ticker, and then getting one of the tables. You could do this as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_fy(ticker, outFile):
    url = f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{ticker}/key-statistics?p={ticker}'
    print(url)

    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html5lib")

    title = soup.title.text
    print(title)

    for tr in soup.table.find_all('tr'):
        row = [td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')]
        print(f'{row[0]:30}  {row[1]}')
    
get_fy("LMT", "test.txt")
```

Which would display:

```
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/LMT/key-statistics?p=LMT
Lockheed Martin Corporation (LMT) Valuation Measures & Financial Statistics
Market Cap (intraday) 5         106.48B
Enterprise Value 3              115.73B
Trailing P/E                    15.46
Forward P/E 1                   13.74
PEG Ratio (5 yr expected) 1     2.79
Price/Sales (ttm)               1.61
Price/Book (mrq)                16.87
Enterprise Value/Revenue 3      1.75
Enterprise Value/EBITDA 7       11.33
```

There should only ever be one `<title>` tag, so a `.find_all()` call is not needed (it would always give you just a single item list). The site also needed a user-agent to be added before returning an suitable HTML.

Comment: Martin, Thanks for the help. I succeeded in importing the requests package and it worked. When I moved on the the <td> elements on https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/LMT/key-statistics?p=LMT

Comment: You're welcome! For that URL you seem to need to add a user-agent to the request before it returns anything. I've updated the script to show you how to get info from the first table.

Comment: Martin, Thanks again. I implemented the code you provided. It's finding the title but coming up with 0 rows, I'm running on a pc mot a mac. Do I need to modify the header?

Comment: No the header is just to pretend to the server that you are a real browser. I've just retested the script and it still works fine for me?  (on Windows)